# Normalizing a single row with multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statistics

I am writing a classification algorithm for classification and I am running all my continuous variables through a MinMaxScaler() so that their values range from 0-1. During the training and testing period, I am able to do this successfully with the data.

The issue I am having is when I am predicting. Rather than an entire dataframe, I am loading in a single row of features in which I want a prediction. An example of the features being used to train (before normalization or factorization for categorical) is:

```
lst = [50000,1, 1, 1,37,0,0,0,0,0,0,64400,57069,57608,19394,
       19619,20024,2500,1815,657,1000,1000,800]
```

I then convert this into a Series, then to a dataframe and transpose this with this code:

```
 ud_df = pd.Series(lst)
 ud_df = ud_df.to_frame()
 ud_df = ud_df.T
 ud_df.columns= ['LIMIT_BAL', 'SEX', 'EDUCATION', 'MARRIAGE', 'AGE', 
'PAY_0', 'PAY_2', 'PAY_3', 'PAY_4', 'PAY_5', 'PAY_6', 'BILL_AMT1', 
'BILL_AMT2', 'BILL_AMT3',
'BILL_AMT4', 'BILL_AMT5', 'BILL_AMT6', 'PAY_AMT1', 'PAY_AMT2', 'PAY_AMT3', 
'PAY_AMT4', 'PAY_AMT5', 'PAY_AMT6']
```

I then split categorical and numerical datatypes apart. For this examples sake, let us assume that the dataframe ud_df contains all continuous values.

I want to run the same MinMaxScaler() normalization that I did on the training and testing set:

```
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(ud_df)
var1 = scaler.transform(ud_df)
var1
```

When I run this, I am getting all 0s as the output:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0.]])
```

Is there any other way I can normalize this entire row to a range of 0 and 1 like on my training and testing set? Conceptually, if I recall correctly, the math involved in the normalization is contingent on the max of that entire column (which I have 30k rows so that max can be found for specific columns).

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you not making prediction on the test data? You cannot normalise a row, because then you are trying to normalise a single row across all columns which is wrong.

Comment: I have normalized the entire data before splitting into test and train sets. I have a definition created in which the user can enter specific values for the columns used for testing and training. I then want to do the .predict() and the same for the probability on the user inputted data. The only issue is that data that the user entered is not in the scale of 0-1 like the data being used to train and test. I feel that this would lead to very bad performance of my model if the features are completely different. I am using XGBoost as my classifier if that helps.

Comment: That's a problem. What are you using your test set for ? The user input isn't sufficient that you use it min max scaling. Alternate way is, calculate the min max values of each column from train-test, using those values, write a simple function for normalising.

Comment: I am using my test set to evaluate the performance of my model, using data that my model has never seen or been trained with. Additionally, every column has bounds that are vastly different so I figured normalization would be needed for those continuous features. Could you further explain the formula and/or how to do the very last line of your comment?

Comment: You need to use the same instance of Min-Max-Scaler (or at least a scaler that is identically initilaized) that you already applied to your training and test set in order to correctly scale your manually created record.

Comment: @Viktor Yes I tried using that but the issue is that every single row for each column is now 0.0

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you are using a new instance of MinMaxScaler for your new dataframe, however you need to use the same instance of the scaler that you already applied to your training dataset. Everthing else does not make sense because you train your model based on the scaling that you already used in your training dataset. If you use another scaler then the trained model does not apply to your new data if the new data is in the same range as your training data (let's not consider the case where the scaler does nothing to the dataset).

The scaler you use above has just one record. That does not work. To be more specific the scaler may also throw an error (which it does not but returns 0). If you pass in one value then this value is both the min and max value at the same time, thus (value-min)/(max-min) is actually 0/0 because value==max==min -> does not work out. If you have two values then the smaller one will be scaled to 0 and the bigger one is scaled to 1,
(smaller_value-smaller_value)/(bigger_value-smaller_value) -> 0 and 
(bigger_value-smaller_value)/(bigger_value-smaller_value) -> 1. Only if you have three distinct values then you get one value between (0,1).

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas

train_set = pandas.DataFrame({'c':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[3, 2, 3]})

s = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(train_set)
s.transform(train_set)

manual_input = pandas.DataFrame({'c':[2], 'b':[2]})

# wrong
s2 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit(manual_input)
print(s2.transform(manual_input))

# right
print(s.transform(manual_input))
```

Output:

```
[[0. 0.]] # wrong scaler instance
[[0.  0.5]] # right scaler instance
```

What you do with values in your manual_input which get scaled in the range up to 0 and above 1 depends on your logic. Maybe you want to set all values below 0 to 0 and above 1 to 1 otherwise your model may do unforeseen things. In the long run you should include these values in your model training or filter them as outliers if they shall never be considered.

Comment: I think I am understanding this. I am faced with this error when changing my code to reflect what you have explained to do: 'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,19) (21,) (1,19)'

Comment: Is another method to go to the beginning to find the max and min for each columns, then perform that calculation you provided for the rows with continuous variables using the max and min for the respective column?

Comment: Problem has been solved. I went in by hand and normalized the data as soon as it was read from the CSV, and applied a similar formula for the prediction data.

Comment: The scaling is done (if not other specified) on the columns of a dataframe. If you do not limit the columns then all columns with numeric values are scaled by their respective column.